# why does python add another backslash to \i

Tags: python

I thought I understood backslash escaping, but I don't get this behaviour:

```
foo = '\t'
```

gives the same string (i.e. `\t`) when I type `foo` in the Python interpreter, whereas

```
bar = '\i'
```

gives `\\i`. What's happening? I want to have just `\i`, because I'm writing it to a `.tex` file that I'm then compiling, and this seems to mess up the LaTeX commands.

Edit: it was in fact not this that was messing up my latex, as the answers below show

Comment: Gives? Do you print? How?

Comment: good point, I mean when I type the variable in the interpreter (so I guess that calls print on it)

Comment: @funklute It's not exactly "printing". `print` gives a `__str__` representation of the object, and directly typing the variable gives a `__repr__` one.

Comment: When you type the variable in the interpreter, it doesn't use `print()`, it uses `repr()`.

Comment: Cool, so does writing to a file object use print() or repr()?

Comment: @funklute `file_object.write()` expects a character buffer (a string), so you should put a string there. Let's say you want to save a list content, the one you get using `print [1, 2, 3]`. You can't do `file_object.write([1, 2, 3])` directly. Though, you _can_ do `write(str([1, 2, 3]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"\t"` is a tab (one character), `"\i"` contains *two* characters, the first of which is escaped by `__repr__`.

```
In [51]: len("\t")
Out[51]: 1

In [52]: len("\i")
Out[52]: 2
```

**Edit:** If you write to a file, your output will be fine.

```
with open("o.tex", "w") as o:
    o.write(">>>\t|\i|\t<<<\n")
```

The content of `o.tex` will then be

```
>>>     |\i|    <<<
```

You can see the two tabs `\t` as whitespace while all other characters are as-is.

Comment: that makes sense. If writing to a file object, is the __repr__ used? or the __str__ representation (as mentioned in the comments on the actual question)